# Cannot group by bit column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, bit

In sql server 2005, i in the query builder, i select "Add group by" to automatically
add the group by clause to all of the fields i selected. If one or more of those fields are a bit type, i get an error. Why is this? Is casting the column to TINYINT a good fix?

Comment: What is the error? I'm not having a problem using a group by on a bit field.

Comment: column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function- this was my fault because after i look @ it i didn't include it in the group by, so i did then it worked. I'm trying to find a way to take this question down lol.

Comment: Leave it. Show us you code in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a limitation of that tool.  if you just write the actual sql yourself in SQL Server Management Studio, it will work.

here is my test code:

```
CREATE TABLE Test2
(ID INT,
bitvalue bit,
flag char(1))
GO

insert into  test2 values (1,1,'a')
insert into  test2 values (2,1,'a')
insert into  test2 values (3,1,'a')
insert into  test2 values (4,1,'b')
insert into  test2 values (5,1,'b')
insert into  test2 values (6,1,'b')
insert into  test2 values (7,1,'b')

insert into  test2 values (10,0,'a')
insert into  test2 values (20,0,'a')
insert into  test2 values (30,0,'a')
insert into  test2 values (40,0,'b')
insert into  test2 values (50,0,'b')
insert into  test2 values (60,0,'b')
insert into  test2 values (70,0,'b')

select * from test2

select count(*),bitvalue,flag from test2 group by bitvalue,flag
```

OUTPUT

```
ID          bitvalue flag
----------- -------- ----
1           1        a
2           1        a
3           1        a
4           1        b
5           1        b
6           1        b
7           1        b
10          0        a
20          0        a
30          0        a
40          0        b
50          0        b
60          0        b
70          0        b

(14 row(s) affected)

            bitvalue flag
----------- -------- ----
3           0        a
3           1        a
4           0        b
4           1        b

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

The tools don't allow some operations such as indexing or grouping on bit columns. Raw SQL does.

Note, you can't aggregate on bit columns. You have to cast first. Of course, averaging a bit columns is kinda pointless, but MAX/MIN is useful as a OR/AND spanning multiple rows.